# How to specify uploaded filename?

Tags: php, image

// This code helps me submit a picture into my images folder.  However the file keeps its original name because of the function basename. How can I add a specific name to the file?  Like logo.png?

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //PROCESS FORM DATA
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
        $target_file = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
        $upload_dir = "images";

        //Move file
        //False als die niet correct is
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir."/".$target_file)) {
          $message = "File upload succesfull";
        } else {
          $error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
          $message = $upload_errors[$error];
        }
      }
?>
```

Html form:

```
  <form action="upload_logo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    Select .png logo to upload:
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file( $tmpname, $newname )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it is pretty nearly there - just generate the name you want, grab the original file extension and append to make new name

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $tmp_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];

        $target_file = 'logo.' . pathinfo( $_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        $upload_dir = "images";


        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir."/".$target_file)) {
            $message = "File upload succesfull";
        } else {
            $error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
            $message = $upload_errors[$error];
        }
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir."/".$target_file)) {
```

with this one:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $new_file_name)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @ChrisM. if it is the correct answer, please upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks I tried it but could not figure it out, it gave some other errors so I tried the one from RamRaider and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code.

```
$target_file = "image_" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() . '.jpg';//Here name is generated dynamically
$upload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, "folderName/" . $target_file);
```

It always generates unique name of file dynamically. It has `date` and `unique id` inside it. They are changed every time. You don't need to change file name manually here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: I hope it will help you. Cheers